# Broke my Laravel 4 site by changing app/config perms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Title speaks for it self.

I changed permissions in the app/config folder because I wanted a single file to be writable by the program but then decided against it and have tried putting the correct perms back since.

I keep getting `Whoops, something went wrong`. I only ever get this if `app.debug` is false, and nothing is showing in my `laravel.log` file so, not sure what I have done but I can't seem to fix it

I tried changing perms back to what they should be, I used

`chown -R root:root app/storage`

`chmod -R 644 app/storage`

Screenshot

[image]